# Lubuntu installed on XTablet7200. Inverted Y axis on Touchscreen, mouse works fine

Tags: additional-drivers

Newbie here with no coding experience. I need this devise to be mobile so touch is important for my farm works.
I have tried all the usual xinput workarounds on the internet. nothing works after calibration. I now understand it may be a driver problem - DIALOGUE INC PenMount USB. I have downloaded the linux drivers but have no understanding on how to install them. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: Please start with your release of Lubuntu (depending on your release, your desktop could be LXDE or LXQt, let alone the release providing a clue as to your software stack age etc)

Comment: kenny@kenny-xTablet-T7200:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic
kenny@kenny-xTablet-T7200:~$

Comment: ITs all good, after 5 years I worked it out. Downloaded the CORRECT drivers and instructions were easy. Thanks anyways.

Comment: It would be useful for others if you could add some details: where did you download the drivers, what commands did you use to do the install? Cheers.

Comment: yes, my apologies. i found the driver at salt.com.tw   there were other drivers online for penmount usb touchscreens but i found this link to be in my league for installation. I understand salt is now penmount. next to fix the power manager issues of the no screen idle, conflicting issues etc. cheers